# Unit test Observable catch error failing in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

Angular Code:

```
 foo() {
    this.myService.myMethod().subscribe({
      next: () => {
        
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.showError();
        throw err;
      }
    });
  }
```

Unit test in Jasmine

```
 it('#foo should throw error when #myService.myMethod throws error', () => {
   
    // Arrange
    const err = new Error('Test error');
    mockedMyService. myMethod.and.returnValue(throwError(() => err));

    // Act


    // Assert

    try {
      component.foo();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toBe('Test error');
    }
  });
```

The goal of the test is to check if foo method throws error i.e to test throw err; being thrown from error block.

The above test is failing with this message: "Error: Test error"

I have tried the following test case too to check the same but that one also is failing:

```
it('#foo should throw error when #myService.myMethod throws error', () => {
   
    // Arrange
    const err = new Error('Test error');
    mockedMyService. myMethod.and.returnValue(throwError(() => err));

    // Act


    // Assert
expect(() => component.foo()).toThrowError('Test error')
  });
```

Tried the following assert and the failed too:

```
expect(() => component.foo()).toThrow(new Error('Test error'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a function as you have, `throwError` takes an `any` as its parameter, usually an `Error` object.

```
it('#foo should throw error when #myService.myMethod throws error', () => {
    const err = new Error('Test error');
    mockedMyService.myMethod.and.returnValue(throwError(err));

    expect(component.foo()).toThrowError('Test error');
  });
```